# Locked ExtJS grid generates a border when theme variable is set to 0

Tags: javascript, extjs, grid

Even though the theme variable for locked grid separator is set to 0, when resizing the locked column, a new border appears *randomly*. It seems more like an empty space between the grids.

$grid-lockable-separator-border-width: dynamic(0);

[before resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CW9U5.png)
[after resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Htfr.png)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you do not have to use dynamic, which only tells Senchas SCSS that it could be overridden in deeper spheres.

```
// Tested in Classic
// Head
.x-grid-locked .x-grid-inner-locked {
    border-width: 0;
}

// Cells
.x-grid-scrollbar-clipper-locked, .x-grid-scrollbar-locked {
    border-width: 0;
}
```